# Reading custom String resources

Tags: java, android, xml

Im using 2 different xml Files to store data i need. When starting the App i want to read those 2 resources and generate Objects from it.
Let me explain, what it is i'm doing:
The first resource stores event-names like this: `/res/values/event_names.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="event_a">AAAA</string>
    <string name="event_b">BBBB</string>
    <string name="event_c">CCCC</string>
    <string name="event_d">DDDD</string>
</resources>
```

The seconds resource stores the times, that given events kick off: `/res/values/event_times.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="event_a">
        <item>02:00</item>
        <item>11:30</item>
        <item>17:00</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="event_b">
        <item>03:00</item>
        <item>12:30</item>
        <item>18:00</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="event_c">
        <item>04:00</item>
        <item>13:30</item>
        <item>19:00</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="event_d">
        <item>04:30</item>
        <item>10:00</item>
        <item>15:00</item>
        <item>20:00</item>
    </string-array>

</resources>
```

Note, that event names and times have their name in commom. On startup the App will read the event-names first and then find out their correspondent timestamps.

Can i do it the way i planned this out? I'd have to read all the identifiers from the name-resource and then by that identifier get the times.

Comment: One more option is that, you can add custom resources in the asset folder and access the asset.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add all the event names as the first element in your `<string-array>`. This way your event names will be tightly coupled to their respective times.

Comment: Oh.. yeah.. ofc.. Ok how to read out all the String Arrays from that resource?

Comment: AFAIK You can't read all the array data on one go. You need to read your array resources using its id like getStringArray(R.array.event_a). But the logic I posted would remove that extra call to strings.xml because you would first use the id R.string.event_a and then use it to access the array when in fact you could do it in one fetch.

Comment: :/ Looks like im just gonna use a txt then... Because i dont want to rely on hard-coding...

Answer (score 0):

Quick idea:

You can probably save all your information on a file with JSON format in the asset folder as @amalBit suggested in a comment.
Then you don't have to make the parsing since Android comes with a JSON library, and you won't be needing to parse any txt with a custom format.

Or in an uglier way (and I am not writing this hehe), you can just put a JSON directly in your strings.xml in one entry alone. That would save you from reading the asset manually. But I wouldn't do this, because strings.xml has another meaning (which is to store strings you want to translate hehe)

If you want I can post you some code of the first case later.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!-- ================= -->
    <!-- Event Mappings    -->
    <!-- ================= -->
    <eat-comment />

    <array name="event_lists">
        <item>@array/event_a</item>
        <item>@array/event_b</item>
        <item>@array/event_c</item>
    </array>

    <!-- =========== -->
    <!-- Event Lists -->
    <!-- =========== -->
    <eat-comment />

    <string-array name="event_a">
        <item>Event A</item>
        <item>02:00</item>
        <item>11:30</item>
        <item>17:00</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="event_b">
        <item>Event B</item>
        <item>03:00</item>
        <item>12:30</item>
        <item>18:00</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="event_c">
        <item>Event C</item>
        <item>04:00</item>
        <item>13:30</item>
        <item>19:00</item>
    </string-array>
```

Code:

```
List<Event> events = new ArrayList<Event>(); // putting all events into a list
TypedArray eventMappings = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.event_lists);
for (int mappingVar = 0; mappingVar < eventMappings.length(); mappingVar++) {
    int eventId = eventMappings.getResourceId(mappingVar, 0);
    String[] eventInfos = getResources().getStringArray(eventId);
    Event event = new Event(); // your event domain class or whatever info holding class
    for (int infosVar = 0; infosVar < eventInfos.length; infosVar++) {
        switch (j) {
        case 0:
            event.setName(eventInfos[infosVar]);
            break;
        default:
            event.addTime(eventInfos[infosVar]);
            break;
        }
        events.add(event);
    }
}
eventMappings.recycle();    // important
```

Hope that helps :-)